# jQuery Colorbox - final image displayed twice

Tags: jquery, colorbox

I have just started evaluating Colorbox as a simple slideshow viewer which will also behave reasonably well on a touch device.

My requirement is to be able to start a slideshow from a link without displaying thumbnails.

My HTML is simply:

```
<a class='gallery' href='... title='first one'>run slideshow</a>
<a class='gallery' href='... title='second one' />
<a class='gallery' href='... title='third one' />
```

My script is:

```
   $(document).ready(function () {
        $('a.gallery').colorbox({
            slideshow: true,
            rel: 'group1',
            loop: 'false'
        });
    });
```

This works, but for some reason the image count is given as 4 and the third image is displayed twice (as 3 of 4 and 4 of 4). And looping still occurs. And the issue is still there if I remove the loop option.

Clearly my method of initiating the slideshow is not correct, but I can't see what is wrong.

Any clues gratefully received.

Jon

Answer (score 0):

I can't see your code but I guess you could be included jquery library twice in your document by mistake.

I often do it using masterpage too.

I hope it may be helpfull to you..

Comment: No - it's not that. And I am at this stage simply running a standalone HTML page with a CDN reference to the jQuery and jquery.colorbox scripts

Answer (score 0):

In case it helps anyone, I have discovered the issue - the a elements need to be properly terminated - i.e.  rather than . But a very weird impact!

Comment: Sorry - the pseudocode got stripped - but you will get the sense that the HTML needs to be properly formed